# Transpose function reference error in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets, transpose, referenceerror

I am using a form spreadsheet to get data from users and on a separate sheet I am transposing the data using the "=transpose()" function on another sheet in the book. I am getting a Reference error when I delete the data from previous form submission on the first sheet. And when new data is imported to the 1st sheet the Transpose function still produces a reference error.

It looks like once the error is produced then I have to manually put the cell references back into the transpose function... very annoying.

Original: =TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!B2:F25)

My transpose functions all turn into this -------------> =TRANSPOSE({})

Is this happening to anyone else? Is there some kind of workaround?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share the google spreadsheet with us?

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/E5pE0-9kliU/j2cnXffV1XoJ

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question, so people can benefit from it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a great answer here and it works perfectly!

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/E5pE0-9kliU/j2cnXffV1XoJ

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `TRANSPOSE` function in a cell where you want to transpose your array, then add the array to transpose into the function 's parameters Example:

> =TRANSPOSE(A166:L174)